# Creating a Database that can be updated live

Tags: php

This is very hard to explain but I'm going to try.

We run a motor shop that has a QC program. The program was coded in access97 and it's time for an upgrade, we have elected to try a PHP/MySQL approach to do this.

Right now the access software has several pages to the form and each box sends to the database live so when you type something in you don't have to hit a save button or next or anything and when you come back it's there.

Also the forms are driven by an auto-incremented job number that you can punch into a field at the top of the page and it query's the server and displays all the data in the form boxes so you can edit it.

I don't know how to even start this project. I got a working form and an insert.php page but I don't know how to go about the rest.

If I could get a pointer in the right direction that would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Ajax, and an on change event + html

Comment: `The program was coded in access97 and it's time for an upgrade` - No kidding! It was time for an upgrade 10 years ago... It sounds like you are going to be creating something extremely AJAX heavy here, especially if you do this every time a key is pressed, to the extent that I wouldn't even attempt this unless you plan to run this over a LAN only - the web traffic this would generate over the internet would be horrifying. Also, new lines aren't chargeable here on SO, a little readability whitespace goes a long way...

Comment: Whendidtheyliftthewhitespacetax?

Comment: @nickb PrblyWhnThyLftdThVwlTx

Comment: Sorry @nickb :) It's one of those days...

Comment: Yeah. Well the computers are about 13+ years old too so we just purchased all new computers for the company and we are moving on up. I will be doing this over LAN only as we have dedicated fiber lines to all our buildings... Who'd a thought they would have fiber for computers that old?

Comment: What type of form elements are there? Just text inputs, or are there checkboxes, radio buttons, etc?

Comment: Is the job number numeric, or alphanumeric?

Comment: Job number is numeric. There are text inputs and drop downs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a simple example here:

**HTML/JS:**
[shaquin.tk/experiments/ajax.html](http://shaquin.tk/experiments/ajax.html),

**PHP:** [shaquin.tk/experiments/qc.txt](http://shaquin.tk/experiments/qc.txt).

Have a look at the source to see how it works (I also have some comments in my code), feel free to copy it and modify for your own needs.

To sum up how it works:

- When text is typed into a text box, a list of changed elements is updated.
- Every *updateInterval* milliseconds (default 1000), the list is checked. (This helps reduce traffic and lag.) If anything has changed, the PHP file is called to update the database, and the list is cleared.
- If an element loses focus and it has changed (e.g. copy/paste), the PHP file is called.
- The PHP file sanitizes the query, checks for a valid job number, and updates the database.

References:

[AJAX XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)

[setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval)

[addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener)

[encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)
[mysqli_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)

[mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

[mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: Brilliant code. Thank you so much. This will put me on the right direction. Thanks so much!

Comment: @sprocket_3 By the way, what browsers are you targeting? The JS script could be improved by using `getElementsByTagName()` but older versions of IE don't support this.

Comment: @sprocket_3 I will be testing it [here](http://shaquin.tk/experiments/ajax4.html).

Comment: I will be using the lastest version of firefox on all the machines that will access this.

Answer (score 1):

You just want it to save automatically? You'll have to look into JavaScript, and more specifically AJAX. I recommend using the jQuery library. Basically, you're going to want to make an AJAX call every time your form field is modified, and that AJAX call will simply update one field in particular.

I understand you are likely very new to website design, so this might be complicated for you.

I would read through [this W3Schools tutorial.](http://w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp) After reading through that, I'd pay close attention to [this tutorial](http://w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp).

Again, **this is difficult for beginners**. I'd recommend you continue to work at your script, and ask more specific questions here on StackOverflow as time goes on. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to submit the data as an ajax request. That way the data can be sent and returned without the page needing to be reloaded to update the information.